# Облачное сохранение и связь с сервером в Android Studio

Tags: android, google-play-services

Не уверен, что написал название верно, но я ищу информацию, как:

1.добавить в свое приложение облачное сохранение в Google Play;

2.сделать связь приложения с каким-либо сервером. То есть мне необходимо при определенном действии клиента отправлять и получать информацию с сервера. Притом информация для всех едина: при действии одного клиента информация меняется у всех.

Искал сам, но нашел только как это сделать в Unity, а мне нужно чтобы это работало в Android Studio. Спасибо.

Comment: Не совсем понятно чего именно вы хотите добиться, но по второму вопросу вам нужно использовать бекенд в связки с push - уведомлениями. Вам нужна серверная часть, котороя будет хранить ваши данные, а при их изменении будет рассылать всем клиентам уведомлении, что бы они загрузили свежие данные. Изучите Firebase, как мимнимум пуши, но у них и своя БД есть, может быть будет достаточно.

Comment: @Valeriy Мне нужно найти способ добавить в свое приложение авторизацию с GP, что бы я мог там сохранять что-либо, в моем случае это будет лишь одно число. А с сервером примерно то же самое, там будет храниться лишь одно число, общее для всех пользователей, например их количество, и мне нужен способ его изменения и обновления у всех. Этого добра в интернете полно, но опять же, нахожу только для Unity.

Comment: Потому как для приложений такого не нужно. Если и используется то очень редко. Потому и нет готовой реализации. Так как это число где-то нужно хранить и как-то обновлять. Выше указано. Почему не гугл, почему именно гугл плей? Если всё же так сильно хочется, вам нужен "GooglePlay Игры", курите вот эту доку: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart?hl=ru

Comment: @Valeriy Возможен и гугл, я думал все это работает только с сервисами Google Play, но, видимо, ошибался